# Accessing "public" members after bundling with browserify or webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, browserify

I have a `test.js` script which defines a class `App` and which is loaded from an HTML file, and all works.

When I create a `testBundle.js` bundle from `test.js`, using browserify or webpack, the class `App` inside `testBundle.js` seems no more defined.

How should I write the code or what options should I give to browserify to get App defined and use it from HTML as before, but from the bundle?.

The error I get after bundling is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined
```

The html file is the following:

```
<html>
   <script src="testBundle.js"></script>

   <script>
       var app = new App();
   </script>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
'use strict';

class App {
    constructor() {
        console.log("App ctor")
    }
}
```

the command to build the bundle:

```
browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ] test.js  -o testBundle.js
```

It seems to me, looking inside the bundle, that App is actually private.

testBundle.js

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var App = function App() {
    _classCallCheck(this, App);

    console.log("App ctor");
};


},{}]},{},[1]);
```

All this using Javascript from the browser, ES6.

Comment: Sorry but I believe (hope) there are better ways to solve the problem, I'm starting a bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, what you're wanting to do is create a library instead of a regular bundle. If you're using webpack you can specify that you want your output to be a library, which will make it available globally via a namespace, similar to jQuery.

```
// relevant part of your webpack config
// from webpack docs
{
  output: {
    // export itself to a global var
    libraryTarget: "var",
    // name of the global var: "Foo"
    library: "Foo"
  }
}
```

Then you can call all of your functions via Foo:

```
var app = new Foo.App()
var somethingElse = Foo.doSomethingElse()
```

Documentation & examples: https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html#examples

Answer (score 11):

You're trying to access `App` in the global context. However, `App` is not made available globally by default. Node.js makes use of modules, and Browserify respects the encapsulation modules provide. When using tools like Browserify or Webpack, it is most common to have one or more entry point modules (i.e. files) that make use of module imports/require() in order to access other modules.

But if you want to be able to access `App` in the global context within the browser, you can assign a reference to the `App` class to a property of `window` in test.js:

e.g.

```
window.App = App;
```

or

```
Object.assign(window, { App });
```

Comment: this works, but if I have other classes I have to "export" each one using windows.MyClass = MyClass at the end of each script? I hoped there was another solution

Comment: The normal way to access entities from other modules is to use import/export or require(). You're circumventing this by wanting to make all your classes globally accessible which is not how Browserify or Webpack are intended to be used. You probably don't need to have any separate `<script></script>` in your html and should instead have an entry point js file which imports/requires the scripts on which it depends. That should be the entry file you specify to Browserify or Webpack.

Comment: you say "should instead have an entry point js file which imports/requires the scripts", but I'm using javascript from the browser and cannot use import or require...

Comment: This is one of the things Browserify and Webpack take care of. By converting your JS into a single bundle file, they also resolve your imports/exports/requires so your code will work when run in the browser. I strongly recommend spending time reading about Browserify/Webpack, what they offer, why they're useful, and how they work, before continuing with either.

Comment: do you know other bundlers which don't require require/import and "export" the bundled elements into the global scope?

Comment: What you're describing is the concatenation of multiple JS files into a single JS file. There are surely many tools that will do this, not necessarily just for JS. The effect would be the same as including each individual JS file into your html with a `<script src="...">`. Alternatively, if you don't have much code, you could keep it all in one file and thus have no need to concatenate your JS. But ultimately, the cleanest and recommended way to handle multiple JS files is to treat them as modules and bundle them using a module bundler such as Webpack, Rollup, or Browserify.

Comment: You honestly probably shouldn't/don't need to be assigning your classes and vars to the global scope anyway. Use webpack in the way it's designed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack or Browserify bundle your scripts in certain context so you can only contact the classes or functions in that bundled context, which is in somewhere in the bundled script. So when you add another script in HTML, it can't access those bundled script's context. If you want to access App class, as far as I know, you can import/export the new script (which is now just making a new App) into the test.js

Comment: can you specify better whatyou mena for " import/export the new script"?

Comment: Basically I would avoid add new script in html with <script></script> and make webpack entry file includes all the scripts, like, implement App in another file, app.js and import it to test.js (which is entry file)